# I want to know what is the maximum size of NVARCHAR that can be supported by DB2 unique index

Tags: db2, size, nvarchar, unique-index

I want to understand what is the maximum column size (page size) of NVARCHAR column supported by unique index in DB2 LUW 11.1.x. 
For e.g. I need an answer like:
(1) NVARCHAR(512) is maximum size of NVARCHAR column supported by unique index.
(2) X is the maximum byte size for any unique index

I have this link, but its not very clear to me:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001029.html

Answer (score 0):

The page you show indicates that the maximum size of a single column in an index key is pagesize/4 in *bytes*, including overhead; so you need to understand how `NVARCHAR(x)` maps to bytes.

This depends on the setting of the `nchar_mapping` [database configuration parameter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0060937.html).

The default setting is to use 4 bytes per character (CODEUNITS32), so you'd be limited to `NVARCHAR(255)` for a 4k page, `NVARCHAR(511)` for an 8k page, `NVARCHAR(1023)` for a 16k page, and `NVARCHAR(2047)` for a 32k page table space.